# How can I make Today()-365 or now()-365 a variable that is used in an IF statement for the logic test?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, variables

I have a table in excel that I have created using vba and I've created a column called Date_Check. The algorithm of the formula is basically if a fail date is before Today()-365 which is a year ago from now, put the word "bad" in that column else put " Good". The code works on the entire range in the specific column as shown below:

```
Dim LastYear  as Date
'LastYear is the date a year ago  time the code is run 
LastYear = Today() -365

'Date_Check is a column in my table(BigTable)
Range("BigTable[Date_Check]").Formula = "= IF((BigTable[FAILDATE]<  LastYear ), ""Bad"", ""Good"")"
```

I tried to run this code but it gave me the #Name? error on excel. When I troubleshot the code, it showed that the variable LastYear is not being recognized or able to compare with the dates in the Fail date column?

I know putting the Today() -365 directly in the if statement resolves the issue but it makes the code extremely slow:

```
Range("BigTable[Date_Check]").Formula = "= IF((BigTable[FAILDATE]<  (Today() -365)), ""Bad"", ""Good"")"
```

how can I get the LastYear variable to be recognized which will make the code run faster?

Comment: Try replacing of `LastYear = Today() -365` with `LastYear = Date -365`. And change the formula as following: `"= IF((BigTable[FAILDATE]<" &  LastYear &  "), ""Bad"", ""Good"")"`. But you asked the same question some days before and If I remember well, you receive the same answer... And this formula cannot be filled down! It works only as it is, filled at once for all the range.

Comment: You need to build your formula correctly.  Try `"= IF((BigTable[FAILDATE]<" & LastYear & "), ""Bad"", ""Good"")"`.  Your code is not using the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, please:

```
Range("BigTable[Date_Check]").Formula = "=IF(YEAR(FAILDATE)<YEAR(TODAY() - 365),""Good"",""Bad"")"
```

Such a formula can also be filled down...

Comment: @Scott Craner: Correct! I tested it and I just copied the resulted formula... Corrected the formula, too.